# IE9 Does not execute $.post in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#tilmeldknap').bind('click', function(){
    alert(333);
    $.post("", $("#signupf").serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(444);
      if(data == '1')
      { 
        $.fancybox.close();
        $("#cocktaillink").fancybox().trigger('click');
      }else if(data == '2')
      {
        alert('Hov.. du skal udfylde alle felterne :-)');
        return false;
      }else if(data == '3')
      {
        alert('Hov.. du er allerede tilmeldt :-)');
        return false;
      }

    });
```

Is what I got. When i click on the #tilmeldknap button, only thing i get is the 333 alert and now the 444. Why is this and how can I solve it?

In chrome it works fine, i get both alerts.

Been looking for a hour or so now, hope for some help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not posting to any url:

```
var myurl = ???;

$.post(myurl, $("#signupf").serialize(), function(data) {
      ...
});
```

Comment: I think he wants to POST to the current url. In a `<form>` tag, `action=""` can be used to achieve this.

Comment: @Karem, if this was the answer, please don't forget to mark it as such.

Comment: @Gabe sorry I forgot, I was going to but I had to wait yesterday.. but there you go ;)